# What is the meaning of these motor characteristic keywords?

Tags: dc-motor

could anybody please explain the following terms?

1. Speed, rated load (RPM)
2. Rated load (N)
3. Rated voltage (V)
4. Max Static Force (N)
5. Max Current (A)
6. Max Load (N)

Answer (score 1):

1. Speed, rated load: This figure is the speed the motor is rated to run at when loaded with its rated load. (see below)
2. Rated load: This is the load the motor is rated to operate under. Essentially, this is the torque at which the motor is designed to operate. It should work fine with lower loads (how low depends on the motor), but exceeding this is not recommended. (are you sure that this metric is in newtons? It should be newton-meters.)
3. Rated voltage: This is the terminal voltage the motor is designed to run at. Basically, this is the voltage you should apply to the motor if you want to use it at full speed under its rated load.
4. Max static force: This is the torque the motor can provide when stalled, i.e., when not spinning. This is also known as stall torque or start-up torque.
5. Max current: Exceeding this current through the motor's windings will cause damage to the motor. Do not attempt to run the motor under this condition, though brief overloads are sometimes okay.
6. Max load: The maximum torque the motor can provide. Do not exceed this, or, again, you will cause damage to the motor.